# how to open someone's shared calendar on thunderbird

Tags: linux, thunderbird, calendar

I just receive an email with title "Sharing invitation: XXX - Calendar" on thunderbird and there is a xml attachment together. I just want to know how I can open this shared calendar.

BTW I am using centos OS.